# Xcode compile error: Can't find an (old) file I used to have

Tags: iphone, xcode, linker, compiler-errors

This is what happens when I try to compile my iPhone app with Xcode v3.1.4

What in the world does it all mean?  (And how do I fix it?)

```
Processing /Users/carol/Documents/MyApp/build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Info.plist TabBarDemo2-Info.plist

cd /Users/carol/Documents/MyApp

setenv PATH 

"/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

<com.apple.tools.info-plist-utility> TabBarDemo2-Info.plist -genpkginfo 

/Users/carol/Documents/MyApp/build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -o /Users/carol/Documents/MyApp/build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app/Info.plist

error: The file “TabBarDemo2-Info.plist” does not exist.
```

Comment: You may wish to accept some answers to ensure some help with your questions.

Comment: Grep through your .xcodeproj files and see where that file is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

This means your "TabBarDemo2-info.plist" is no longer available. You need to make another .plist with the same under the name "TabBarDemo2-info.plist" and then give it the properties your previously had and then everything should work fine. Also when it comes to creating new plist do the following:

Add a new file. Then go under Mac OS X > Resource > Property List.